# How much longitude and latitude does a pixel represent in Google Maps with zero zoom?

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-maps-api-3

In the documentation about this topic [posted here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates) it mentions that the top left corner of [this 256x256 pixel Mercator world map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/pixelCoordinates.png) has the coordinates 180° longitude y aprox. 85° latitude.

I'm developing a Unity3D application (using C#) in which I need to **superpose different items on top of a map** that I have retrieved using simple GET HTTP requests to **the Google Maps API** (maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap), so I need to know which the base scale is so I can extrapolate all the other scales with the mentioned base-2 sizes of every zoom value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource for this is here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale

## Resolution and Scale

Exact length of the equator (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equator#Exact_length_of_the_Equator)) is 40075.016686 km in WGS-84. A horizontal tile size at zoom 0 would be 156543.03 meters:

```
40075.016686 * 1000 / 256 ≈ 6378137.0 * 2 * pi / 256 ≈ 156543.03
```

Which gives us a formula to calculate resolution at any given zoom:

```
resolution = 156543.03 meters/pixel * cos(latitude) / (2 ^ zoomlevel)
```

Some applications need to know a map scale, that is, how 1 cm on a screen translates to 1 cm of a map.

```
scale = 1 : (screen_dpi * 39.37 in/m * resolution)
```

And here is the table to rid you of those calculations. All values are shown for equator, and you have to multiply them by cos(latitude) to adjust to a given latitude. For example, divide those by 2 for latitude 60 (Oslo, Helsinki, Saint-Petersburg).

[image: table]

Here it is tab-delimited (for convenient copy and pasting)

```
zoom    resolution, m/px    scale 96 dpi    1 screen cm is  scale 120 dpi
0   156543.03   1 : 554 678 932 5547 km 1 : 739 571 909
1   78271.52    1 : 277 339 466 2773 km 1 : 369 785 954
2   39135.76    1 : 138 669 733 1337 km 1 : 184 892 977
3   19567.88    1 : 69 334 866  693 km  1 : 92 446 488
4   9783.94 1 : 34 667 433  347 km  1 : 46 223 244
5   4891.97 1 : 17 333 716  173 km  1 : 23 111 622
6   2445.98 1 : 8 666 858   86.7 km 1 : 11 555 811
7   1222.99 1 : 4 333 429   43.3 km 1 : 5 777 905
8   611.50  1 : 2 166 714   21.7 km 1 : 2 888 952
9   305.75  1 : 1 083 357   10.8 km 1 : 1 444 476
10  152.87  1 : 541 678 5.4 km  1 : 722 238
11  76.437  1 : 270 839 2.7 km  1 : 361 119
12  38.219  1 : 135 419 1.35 km 1 : 180 559
13  19.109  1 : 67 709  677 m   1 : 90 279
14  9.5546  1 : 33 854  339 m   1 : 45 139
15  4.7773  1 : 16 927  169 m   1 : 22 569
16  2.3887  1 : 8 463   84.6 m  1 : 11 284
17  1.1943  1 : 4 231   42.3 m  1 : 5 642
18  0.5972  1 : 2 115   21.2 m  1 : 2 821
```

---

Other Resources:

- http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#designing_overlay_gm_mve.htm